# How to decouple reference to python object

Tags: python, object, reference

I create the following list of list containing False:

```
array=[[False] * 3] * 5
```

How can I change only value value?

```
array[1][0]='change only this'
```

Currently the result is

```
[['change only this', False, False],
 ['change only this', False, False],
 ['change only this', False, False],
 ['change only this', False, False],
 ['change only this', False, False]]
```

which is not desired. I understand each column is one single object [False] * 3]. How can I decouple them from each other. Do I need to make them immutable somehow?

Answer (score 2):

You could write

```
array = [[False] * 3 for _ in range(5)]
```

This creates five separate three-element lists and stores the references in `array`.